# Gettings nans on using lu factorization for solving singular square matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

I have singular matrix A(10*10) which is rank deficient(rank=9) and I have vector b which is in range space of A. Now I am interested in some solution to Ax=b. For concreteness here is my A

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.86826141,  0.        ,
             0.        ,  0.88788426,  0.        ,  0.4089203 ,  0.88134901],
           [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.46416372,  0.        ,  0.        ,
             0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
           [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.31303966,
             0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
           [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
             0.        ,  0.3155742 ,  0.        ,  0.64059294,  0.        ],
           [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.51349938,
             0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.53593509,  0.        ],
           [ 0.        ,  0.01252787,  0.        ,  0.6870415 ,  0.        ,
             0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
           [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
             0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
           [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.16643105,  0.        ,
             0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
           [ 0.08626592,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
             0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.66939531],
           [ 0.43694586,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
             0.95941661,  0.        ,  0.52936733,  0.79687149,  0.81463887]])
```

b is generated using `A.dot(np.ones(10))`. Now I wanted to solve this using lu factorization and for that I did this following

```
lu_fac=scipy.linalg.lu_factor(X)
scipy.linalg.lu_solve(lu_fac,b)
```

Which gives

```
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Also lu_factor seems to be working fine in this case(some time it does give run time warning saying *"Diagonal number %d is exactly zero. Singular matrix"*). For completeness here is the code for verifying PLU from lu_factor is same as A :

```
L=np.tril(lu_fac[0])
np.fill_diagonal(L,1)
U=np.triu(lu_fac[0])
perm=np.arange(10)
ipiv=lu_factor[1]
for i in range(10):
  temp=perm[i]
  perm[i]=perm[ipiv[i]]
  perm[ipiv[i]]=temp
np.allclose(X[perm,:],L.dot(U))
```

Now I know my matrix is singular and there are infinitely many solutions to my problem. But I am interested in any solution and I am just confused why lu factorization fails, can't it set free variables to 0 and find some solution as we are taught? Also what is the deal with the run time warning  *"Diagonal number %d is exactly zero. Singular matrix"*. Note I am not interested in svd/qr approach to solve this, I am just curious to know why lu fails for singular matrices. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0 / lu_fac[0][9, 9]
```

returns `nan` because that entry - the last diagonal entry of U, is zero. So this `nan` becomes the value of the 9-th variable. Then it's substituted in the equations above, and naturally, the rest comes out as `nan`, too. SciPy's LU code, or rather the Fortran code it wraps, is not designed for rank-deficient matrices, so it is not going to make up values for the variables that can't be determined.

> Also what is the deal with the run time warning "Diagonal number %d is exactly zero. Singular matrix".

The warning is clear: the algorithm detected a singular matrix, which is not expected. It also tells you that the implementation is not intended for use with singular matrices.

> have vector b which is in range space of A

That's theoretically. In practice, one can't be sure about anything being in the range space of a rank-deficient matrix because of the errors inherent in the floating point arithmetics. You can compute `b = A.dot(...)` and then try to solve Ax=b, and there won't be a solution because of the errors introduced when manipulating floating point numbers.

By the way: you mentioned that PLU factorization exists for every square matrix, but  SciPy is not necessarily designed to compute it. For example,

```
scipy.linalg.lu_factor(np.array([[0, 1], [0, 0]]))
```

returns a matrix with NaNs. In your case, NaN appear later, when attempting to find a solution and encountering a zero diagonal element of factor U.

Comment: So does that mean LU is not recommended for singular matrices? And if I understand correctly the issues is not knowing something is 0 or close to zero? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. LU is for solving a system exactly, which is the wrong thing to try with singular matrices. This is in contrast with methods involving orthogonal decompositions which present a robust approach based on the minimization of a sum of squares.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218770/when-does-a-square-matrix-have-an-lu-decomposition), a matrix has an LU factorization if and only if `rank(A11) + k >= rank([A11 A12]) + rank([A11 A21])`. In your case, `rank(A11) = 3`, `k = 5`,
 and `rank([A11 A12]) + rank([A11 A21]) = 9`. So you matrix does not satisfy the conditions and does not have an LU factorization.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But lu_factor does PLU decomposition which always exist. Also I have verified that PLU I am getting from lu_factor is same as A. So its not that. Things fail while doing lu_solve. Thanks again.